# Applying different condition on the same column in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an input table. I need to get the output based on a few conditions.

1. If Type ="Deposit" then Output = Value
2. If Type ="Card" and Condition in("approved","approved:conditionally") then Output = Value,
   If Type ="Card" and Condition = "referred" then Output = 0.4*Value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Based on your sample data the only case which changes value in output is `If Type ="Card" and Condition = "referred"`, so you can simplify logic to just below

```
CASE 
  WHEN (type, condition) = ('Card', 'referred') THEN value * 0.4
  ELSE value
END output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
CASE 
WHEN type = 'Deposit' THEN value
WHEN type = 'Card' AND condition IN ('approved', 'approved:conditionally') THEN value
WHEN type = 'Card' AND condition IN ('referred') THEN value * 0.4
END
```